# Applying color coding to a Grafana grid based on field comparison

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am currently working with Grafana and have implemented a grid visualization to track application versioning across different environments (e.g., development, production). Each row in the grid represents an application, and the columns correspond to different environments.

[image]
I need to identify if the Dev environment is lagging behind the Prod  environment. In such cases, I would like to apply a specific color, such as orange, to highlight this lag.

Specifically, I want to:

1. Compare the values of Field A and Field B in each row.
2. If Field A exceeds Field B, I want the cell(A) background colour to be red.
3. If the above condition isn't met, I want the cell background
   colour to be green.

I've explored the available options in Grafana but haven't found a built-in way to
achieve this colour coding based on multiple field comparisons. Is there a way to accomplish this in Grafana? If so, what approach or plugin can I use? If not, are there any workarounds or alternative solutions you recommend?

I appreciate any guidance or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: Coloring row based on a single cell is [not supported anymore](https://community.grafana.com/t/table-row-color/45765). The best I can imagine in this situation - color a single cell, that will contain flag if two cells are equal. And even it can be accomplished only if value of your metric actually means nothing and can be reused (based on the assumption you're using Prometheus as data source)